# How to get okhttp stored cache size as bytes?

Tags: android, caching, kotlin, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm using `retrofit2` and `okhttp` in my android project and cache response data 
from server side.

Is there any way to find that how many bytes stored in cache storage and log it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `OkHttpClient.cache().size()`  ?

Answer (score 2):

You can take it from `Retrofit` instance by the following way:

```
val cacheSize = (retrofit.callFactory() as OkHttpClient).cache()?.size()
```